# Ansible variables and text replacement

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use Ansible to replace a sample text with a variable.  I have tried using no quotes, "", and '', but nothing seems to work.  I also tried using the replace module and the lineinfile module.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
- hosts: 10.1.1.10
  become: yes

  vars:
    server1:
      1a: "ED:5A:13:AA:34:20"
      2a: "ED:5A:13:AA:34:21"

  tasks:
  - name: Replace mac address in file  
    lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/file.json.j2
      regexp: 'FILL_THIS_IN'
      line: "{{ server1.1a }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Excerpt from [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name) about variables:

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores. **Variables should always start with a letter.**

So you should refactor to:

```
server1:
  a1: "ED:5A:13:AA:34:20"
  a2: "ED:5A:13:AA:34:21"
```

and in the code:

```
line: "{{ server1.a1 }}"
```

Comment: Konstantin Suvorov, I appreciate your help in finding my mistake.  I had read that about variables, but I guess I overlooked that.  Thank you also for formating my code correctly.